# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:scoped-proxy'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, aop

I have a Spring MvC project using JPA and Oracle as DB, I have this bean declaration in my servlet.xml file, but when I run a test

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<bean id="bbtra" 
        class="com.bonanza.commons.services.TranslationDB"
        autowire-candidate="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

I got this error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:scoped-proxy'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the `*.xsd` files are referenced by `https://` instead of `http://`, but that is not the problem, I am just mentioning it. The minimal change to your XML file fixing the problem is moving up `spring-tx.xsd` to be right behind `tx`. Then also the highlighting in your XML editor changes, i.e. in IntelliJ IDEA you will see the AOP stuff go from grey to green. What I mean is:

```xml
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
  "
>

  <bean id="bbtra"
    class="com.bonanza.commons.services.TranslationDB"
    autowire-candidate="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Now all schema locations `schema/foo` and `schema/foo/spring-foo.xsd` form pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably schema location of the aop namespace is not specified:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop https://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!-- bean definitions here -->

</beans>
```

Comment: All necessary elements were specified in the OP's configuration, as you can easily see if you check what he posted. What was wrong was the order of schema locations.

Comment: @kriegaex Unfortunately namespace declarations were added after this answer was given. Originally it was a reasonable guess.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry. Please accept my apology, I didn't compare the edit timestamp to your answer's.